# changing ip of server running docker

Tags: docker

I'm new in Docker. 
I had software installed with docker on the server running RedHat 7- which work okay.

We change the ip of the server and now when we go to the software we get: 
 Connection problem

Is the connection problem connected to the change done in the ip of the server?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly. You will need to add some detail to your question on what the software is, what you run to get the error etc. You'll probably get a better response to server type questions on https://serverfault.com

Comment: the problems was connected to process in the software and not to the docker. Thanks.